# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchTracker'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have come across this issue in one of my projects. This specific file tracks data so that is can be placed on a map in an application.

I have looked elsewhere on StackOverflow for an explanation and resolution for the issue, but I haven't found anything that works. Any insight would be appreciated.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const API_HOST = '...';
const ENDPOINTS = [...];
const defaultState = {...};

const useTracker = ({ api = 'all' }) => {
    const [tracker = {}, updateTracker] = useState(defaultState);

    async function fetchTracker() {
        let route = ENDPOINTS.find(({ id } = {}) => id === api);
        let response;

        if (!route) {...}

        try {...} catch (e) {...}

        const { data } = response;

        updateTracker((prev) => {
            return {
                ...prev,
                state: 'ready',
                data
            };
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchTracker();
    }, [api]);

    return {
        fetchTracker,
        ...tracker
    };
};

export default useTracker;
```

Thanks

Comment: You simply need to add `fetchTracker` in your useEffect dependencies
    `useEffect(() => {
        fetchTracker();
    }, [api, fetchTracker]);`

Comment: @Nico_: Which, however, is probably not what the OP wants since `fetchTracker` will be different every time `useTracker` is called.

Comment: You probably want to use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to create `fetchTracker`, which should depend on `updateTracker` and `api`. Then `useEffect` should just depend on `fetchTracker` only.

Comment: @FelixKling I may be wrong but `fetchTracker` is a function so it won't change (even if the result of this function may change).

Comment: @Nico_: The function declaration is inside `useTracker`. So every time `useTracker` is executed (which is every time a component is rendered) a new "version" of `fetchTracker` is created. Simplified example: `function createFunc() { return () => {};}; console.log(createFunc() === createFunc());`.

Comment: Indeed! You are right, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include it to prevent side effect. To prevent a infinity loop wrap it in useCalback:

```
const useTracker = ({ api = 'all' }) => {
    const [tracker = {}, updateTracker] = useState(defaultState);

    const fetchTracker = React.useCallback(async () => {
        let route = ENDPOINTS.find(({ id } = {}) => id === api);
        let response;

        if (!route) {...}

        try {...} catch (e) {...}

        const { data } = response;

        updateTracker((prev) => {
            return {
                ...prev,
                state: 'ready',
                data
            };
        });
    },[api]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchTracker();
    }, [api, fetchTracker]);

    return {
        fetchTracker,
        ...tracker
    };
};
```

Comment: I tried this and now I am getting a different warning `The 'fetchTracker' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook change on every render. To fix this, wrap the 'fetchTracker' definition into its own useCallback() Hook`

Comment: Sorry typed it in wrong. It worked, thanks! 

Can you provide more of an explanation or link me to something with more of an explanation. This is my first time running into this kind of issue and I am trying to learn.

Comment: The react docs are great: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback. and Kent's article is great too: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback